# Function of earth screw terminals in power supplies with plastic cases

Tags: power-supply, insulation

This is about use of earth screw terminals which are often provided in power supplies.

Below is an Embedded Switch Mode Power Supply with a metallic case:

[image]

Here I can understand how the earth wiring is useful in case of line is touching to the case. This would save someone being exposed to line voltage.

On the other hand below is a DIN Rail Power Supply with a plastic case:

[image]

It also has an earth terminal. In this case how is the earth wiring useful since the case is already insulator itself (plastic)?

Comment: Prevent it from floating, filter interference into it, requirements by standards, for that specific product only the designer knows exactly why.

Comment: I see so it could be something else than safety

Comment: provide a connection to deal with more than one cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EMC is the first thought - earthing certain line filters inside the plastic case may be a requirement for correctly using this power supply.

However, the earth symbol has a circle around it so it means "protective earth" (or PE) i.e. it is used for reasons of safety and the circled earth symbol is usually implying that the unit is built and CE marked so, it's mandatory to provide a PE wire.

[image]

So, that's its main function but, because it is always required to be connected to a PE, the PE may also be used for EMC reasons and the CE marking/EU directive applied might require it for these secondary reasons.

The unit appears to have  CE mark so check its documentation to see what that says about the PE. As for what it protects, it's possible that the step-down transformer relies on a PE to protect the output circuits from rising to unsafe levels. Maybe the output is actually connected to PE?

Comment: Data sheet specifically warns "Do not use the power supply without proper grounding (Protective Earth). Use the terminal on the input block for earth connection."

Comment: That is not exactly a fully insulated case either. It looks like it would be rather too easy to poke the low voltage wires between the slats in the top while fishing cables around. some of their imaging also shows some significant heat-sinks in there which would need to be grounded if the case were deemed to be insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. Functional diagram showing internal earth connection to input filter. Source: [PIC 120E.242C](http://www.pulspower.com/fileadmin/Dateien/pdf/pic120e242c.pdf) page 9.*

[image]

*Figure 2. A typical mains filter. Source [TDK-Lambda FAQ](https://uk.tdk-lambda.com/faq/question.aspx?id=99).*

The earth link of Figure 1 is probably very similar to that required in Figure 2.